# C++ lock_guard vs mutex.lock()

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex

I have a loop like this:

```
for (auto &i : elements)
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(i.mutex);
  some heavy writing to disk with i
}
```

Throwing an error:

```
tpp.c:62: __pthread_tpp_change_priority: Assertion `new_prio == -1 || (new_prio >= __sched_fifo_min_prio && new_prio <= __sched_fifo_max_prio)' failed.
```

Can someone explain me, why this loop does not throw the error:

```
for (auto &i : elements)
{
  i.mutex.lock();
  some heavy writing to disk with i
  i.mutex.unlock();
}
```

My knowledge about C++ multithreading is more from a practical viewpoint, so both loops always seemed equal to me. However, the first one is causing me much more problems than the second. It's also not always the same error, I get some invalid pointers with loop #1 as well, while the second loop has not yet crashed in many runs.

Any guess, what may cause the problem without knowing the rest of the code?

Comment: The problem is very likely to be within the rest of your code. Something somewhere has undefined behaviour, and it's impossible to guess what or where.

Comment: But isn't it weird, that it crashes within seconds using loop #1, but does not crash at all with loop #2? What does it say about the error in the rest of the code? Some memory mismanagement, so creating the lock_guard causes the problem as would the creation of any object?

Comment: Undefined behaviour is weird sometimes, and sometimes it appears to work. It can also affect apparently unrelated parts of a program. The most effective way to find it is to assume that anything could be wrong, read carefully and think even more carefully.

Comment: try to use `std::unique_lock` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I guess I found my answer. Thanks everyone for sorting things out. @molbdnilo was closest to the problem. Indeed there was an undefined behaviour in the rest of my code. Running Valgrind showed me invalid read and write operations on the lock_guard. My mutex is stored in a shared pointer, which is being reset by another thread without being locked beforehand. Consequently the mutex is being destroyed, while the other thread holds a lock_guard on it. I guess that's a problem?

In loop #2 the actual scenario is i->mutex.lock() and i->mutex.unlock(). So here was no error thrown, likely because the first lock sometimes just happened on an object, that was being released soon after. The unlock then was called on an already unlocked mutex, which is undefined behaviour as well but didn't cause any error for now.

Answer (score 0):

`tpp.c:63: __pthread_tpp_change_priority: Assertion` is a known problem and [solved](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2008-05/msg00071.html):

In brief, the problem is caused by repeated locking of a fast mutex, and solved by using a recursive mutex, and the default pthread_mutex_t is not recursive. Is it possible that there's pthread_mutex_t deeply inside the thread running code ??
BTW, to make the mutex recursive, please set the mutex attribute with attribute PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP.

Comment: I read this answer as well. But I am not sure, if a recursive mutex is what I want. When I understood correctly, the number of calls to unlock() have to be equal to the number of calls to lock() before. I think this would not resolve my issue, rather create other ones as I don't understand what part is causing it.

Comment: the problem is the repeated locking of a fast mutex, probably in the right condition also the classical method lock/unlock will fail. So the lock/unlock is not the right solution but only the lucky one. In the first case probably the call to constructor/destructor of lock_guard cause the right delay to let the problem highlights.